# code for prevent New Line in Textarea when ENTER key is pressed doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the enter key to submit text in a text area, howver when the key is pressed the vertical sidebar flashes; I don't want this to happen.

as a solution i am trying to use the JS

> event.preventDefault()

method to prevent the default action of enter key. I just don't know why it doesn't work.

Note: the following code is taken from this site.

```js
function preventMoving(event){
  var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
          event.preventDefault(); 

    }
}
```

```css
textarea { 
    overflow:auto; 
    resize:none; 
    width:90%; 
    height:300px; 
}
```

```html
<textarea onkeyup="preventMoving(event);"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listening to keyup event is too late for calling preventDefault, try listening to keypress or keydown instead.

```js
function preventMoving(event){
  var key = event.keyCode;
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
          event.preventDefault(); 

    }
}
```

```css
textarea { 
    overflow:auto; 
    resize:none; 
    width:90%; 
    height:300px; 
}
```

```html
<textarea onkeypress="preventMoving(event);"></textarea>
```

Comment: brilliant answer and to the point, short, concise, and informative . thanks very much. sorry I can't upvote as I need more than 15 reputations. but I accepted the answer

Comment: But why implement a fallback from `event.keyCode` to `event.which` in `key` when never using it? (was already in the OP but should have been fixed! ;))

Comment: @ConstantinGroß it was in question, just in case i used to answer